# Google Cloud Datatore Go Client doesn't close the connection by default?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I've had a bunch of issues **migrating** from App Engine on **Go 1.9** to **1.11**.

I noticed the **memory usage grew** insanely when I followed the guide how to migrate. Before it was at a constant ~**50-60 MB**, but now it grew to **1.5 GB** quickly and instances started failing.

But then I noticed that all examples showing how to use the GCP Datastore just replaced the previous

`datastore.Get()`

with

`dsClient := datastore.NewClient(...) dsClient.get()`

Then, when I looked closer at this client, it created a connection but never seem to close it, so when I added a `defer dsClient.Close()` after I created a new client *(basically in every call handler)*, the memory started going up from around ~**60-80 MB** to ~**500 MB** and then dropped; it kept going like this, but it was stable so I figured it did a GC every now and then. However, after a couple days it failed again and requests took forever and new instances were created until the cap was reached *(previously it failed quicker)*.

So I wonder if I should just create one Datastore Client in main instead? Is it a good practice? And, if so, why do all examples show it being created in the call handle, and why is there never call to close the connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost did the same but the godoc says to create a single client and reuse it for all datastore operations. There is no need to close the connection.

```
    // Create a datastore client. In a typical application, you would create
    // a single client which is reused for every datastore operation.
    dsClient, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, "my-project")
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error.
    }
```

https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore

Comment: There we go, thanks, I totally missed that! The go 1.9 to 1.11 didn't mention it (clearly atleast)